# Magento 2 add custom checkbox after payment method

Tags: magento2, checkout, extension-attributes

In checkout page, after payment methods I want to add custom checkbox and save it's value in sales_order and quote table when click on placeorder button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow below link,
this is helpful for you

https://github.com/boldcommerce/magento2-ordercomments